# how to pass an object to another object in java

Tags: java, object

I am new to java in general but I am having a lot of trouble with objects specifically. I have a project to pass an object to  another object. I've looked all over the internet for help, my online java textbook doesn't explain objects in detail. So my question is, how would you pass an object to another object.

-Thank you in advance

Comment: `I am having a lot of trouble with objects specifically`, Can you show the code causing trouble ??

Comment: You might pass an `Object` as a constructor or a method argument.

Comment: Can U Show D Code...?

Comment: I don't have any code because i have no clue where to start.

Comment: One word... Constructor

Comment: What is your online java textbook?  It must have this!

Comment: Take a look at [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). It should help you in your learning.

Comment: Start by explaining the context, what you are trying to achieve... What is the purpose of your objects...

Comment: I am mainly confused with passing things. for example the only way i know how to use objects is if i make the variables static and i know that i shouldn't do that and i think i need to pass something but i don't know what.

Comment: Constructor or setter method..

Comment: I am trying to pass one object to another. Those were the only guidelines i was given. I guess that i could do anything.

Comment: my java textbook is blue pelican

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an object o1 to another object o2 through calling a method of o2 (or a constructor of o2's class in particular; constructors as you know are special types of methods).

I suggest you start by figuring out what this code below does.

How many persons are there?
What are their names at different moments of the execution of the program?
How many times and where a Person object is passed to a Person object?
How many times and where a String object is passed to a Person object?

If you digest this, you'll be good for now.

```
class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person(Person p){
        this.name = p.name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person t1 = new Person("Joe");
        Person t2 = new Person("John");
        System.out.println(t1.getName());
        System.out.println(t2.getName());
        t1.setName("Mark");
        System.out.println(t1.getName());
        System.out.println(t2.getName());
        Person t3 = new Person(t1);
        System.out.println(t3.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Messaging between objects is a core concept in object-oriented programming.  To "pass an object to another object" generally just means that one object exposes a method which accepts the type of another object as a parameter to that method.  It could be something as simple as this:

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
       this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
       return name;
    }
}

class Car {
    private Person driver;

    public void setDriver(Person driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in the code, you'd have an instance of a `Car` and an instance of a `Person`, and you'd call that method:

```
carInstance.setDriver(personInstance);
```

Those instances could have been created lots of different ways.  Perhaps even as simple as:

```
Person personInstance = new Person();
personInstance.setName("David");
Car carInstance = new Car();
```

Comment: +1 Naming Convention _pleease_

Comment: and `setDriver` should be is not adding anything :)

Comment: @nachokk: Good point.  When I started writing the code, I was intending to add "passengers" to a list of passengers, but decided to keep it slightly simpler for the OP.  I just forgot to update the method name.  Thanks!

Comment: I was actually referring to letter casing

Comment: @peeskillet: Should I fix something?  I'm not entirely familiar with Java conventions, most of my work is in C#.

Comment: method starts with lower case

Comment: i edited for you xD `string` doesn't exist in java, and i add `this.` :)